# Accessing Tumblr feed using their iOS SDK/API

Tags: ios, tumblr

I'm trying to create a Tumblr application.

It has to be an application for iOS 7. The requirement 
is to use the TMTumblrSDK but as far as I can see, the documentation is lacking.

I figured out how to use the user authentication but I just can't figure out 
how to get my own feed.

Comment: What have you tried? Posting some code can help others continue on your path and add the features you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
Example:

```
NSArray* paramsKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"limit",
                       @"offset",
                       @"type",
                       nil];
NSArray* paramsVals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", limitNextPage],
                       [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", _dashboardOffsetAudio],
                       @"audio",
                       nil];
NSDictionary *paramsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:paramsVals forKeys:paramsKeys];

[[TMAPIClient sharedInstance]dashboard:paramsDict callback:^(id response, NSError *error){
    if(!error) {
        NSDictionary *dashboard = response;
    }
}];
```

Most important part is the static block "sharedInstance". Apparently the whole SDK works with the Tumblr meta data standards. So if you can`t find something that you need you can look into the Tumblr API documentation which explains al the possibilities: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2.

Explanation:

- paramsKeys: Those are the keys used in the API. Can be found under "/posts – Retrieve Published Posts".
- paramsVals: I use it to make a list of array entires.
- paramsDict: Is to combine the two.
- sharedInstance: This method is used by the whole application to interact with Tumblr. The dashboard requires the use of above parameters and returns a response object which is just an array of what you request.

  I hope that this will be of help to other.